# Raised horizontal lines on plastered walls

Tags: plaster

I have a few of these raised horizontal lines in my house in different rooms.   The walls are plaster and the paint is a semigloss I believe[image]

Comment: A photo that shows more of the wall and things for scale would be helpful.

Comment: Looks like a typical crack in a plaster wall. It happens. It can be taped over and mudded but good luck on making the repair less noticeable than the crack itself. The sanded finish is difficult to mimic.

Comment: If I expand out pic, you won't see it.  The house is 82 years old,  I figured it would have finished settling..but we've had a lot of rain this winter without the ground really freezing.

Comment: What @Jack said… hard to fix without making a megaproject out of it. A flatter paint will make it less obvious.

Comment: That crack has been there a while. It has been painted over. If it was a new crack, the close up picture would show a gap, even a slight one where the plaster separated to form the crack and the 2 different planes of plaster created by the crack, but paint is bridging the crack, so in my opinion it has been there a while, years maybe. There is a small chance it is a "lap mark" created at the time the plaster was being applied that was never flattened out. That is very improbable, due to the way sanded finish is applied.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I painted that wall myself and there was no crack unless i didn't notice it.  Could it be a new crack but the semigloss paint didn't "split" when the crack formed?

Comment: Looks more like a roller edge mark (paint ridge) to me. Would you have rolled in that direction?

Comment: It is highly unlikely the paint would react that way if the wall cracked under it so to speak. There would be some separation, somewhere, so I would think. It appears the paint follows the ridge fairly well, as opposed to pulling away from the wall a bit, with no visible tear, if the crack did happen after painting.